# Moving a cell using CGRectOffset - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, cgrect

I stumbled upon [this](https://github.com/runmad/RMSwipeTableViewCell) fantastic library for implementing table view cell sliding, but there's a few minor differences between what it offers and what I'm looking to have, so I'm continuing with my implementation.

The way the developer moved the table view cells was creative, I thought, in that he used `CGRectOffset()` to add almost padding to the sides of the cell as it moved to look like it was moving.

I want to do something similar for mine, as it seems like the easiest way to accomplish this. However, when I do the following, nothing happens to the cell:

(Just an example):

```
    CGFloat offset = 11;
    self.contentView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.contentView.bounds, offset, 0);
```

I set a breakpoint there, so it's indeed being called when I pan across the cell (it's in the gesture recognizer method). Yet after it gets called, the cell looks identical in position.

And I have this at the beginning, similar to how he set up the view:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.contentView.frame];
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.backgroundView = backgroundView;

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pannedCell:)];
    panGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
}
```

So I'm not sure exactly why it's not working. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the implemented of pannedCell:

Comment: Instead of moving self.contentView.frame, try to move self.view.frame

Comment: @SanjitSaluja There's not much more to it, other than figuring out how much the user has panned, which I just replaced with a static amount to see if it would move to there, which it hasn't.

Comment: @verbumdei Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try that when I'm at my dev box again.